# How to show "number of failed login attempts" on a successful ssh login?

Tags: ssh, pam, fail2ban

I use CentOS 7 on a host. There used to be a report of the number of failed login attempts shown whenever I logged into the machine using SSH. The full banner was something like this:

> Last failed login: Fri May 24 03:58:45 EDT 2019 from x.x.x.x on ssh:notty
>   There were 121 failed login attempts since the last successful login.
>   Last login: Thu May 23 15:52:24 2019 from x.x.x.x

Then I installed fail2ban to prevent these attempts, and after that the line reporting the number of failed logins is gone. At first I thought maybe these bots have decided to not try to login to my machine anymore and there was really no failed login attempts, so the message is gone. But then I realized `lastb` shows a lot of recent attempts. I tried to have a look at `/var/log/secure` but the file does not exist anymore.

As I understand `/etc/pam.d/postlogin` is responsible to show this message at login. Here is the content of that file:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.

session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service !~ gdm* service !~ su* quiet
session     [default=1]   pam_lastlog.so nowtmp showfailed
session     optional      pam_lastlog.so silent noupdate showfailed
```

How do I find out what caused this change? And how do I get that message back?

Answer (score 0):

My Fedora has a man page for `pam_tally2` which says it counts attempted accesses. As well as the module, there is a command of the same name to lookup current values in  `/var/log/tallylog`, but I don't see any entries in there. However, you can try

```
sudo pam_tally2 -u myusername
```

Comment: Thanks. It's strange that this command does not report any failed attempts on my machine. Anyway, my goal is to put this information in ssh banner. More accurately, I want to find out what made this information disappear from the banner, because previously it was there and I whatever I did, I didn't intend to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

For failed login attempts can be found in /var/log/secure

Below is the example

```
 host-1-193 sshd[1644]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
May 24 18:23:46 host-1-193 sshd[1644]: Failed password for root from 10.200.0.1 port 29021 ssh2
May 24 18:23:49 host-1-193 sshd[1644]: Accepted password for root from 10.200.0.1 port 29021 ssh2
May 24 18:23:49 host-1-193 sshd[1644]: pa
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you missed the part of the question that says `/var/log/secure does not exist`.